# Proving that limits of sequences are a "special case of continuity"

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

I'm working through a set of lecture notes for self-study, and they present the following fact:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y = \{0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots\}$. Then $\{p_n\}$, a sequence in $X$, converges to $p$ in the $\epsilon-N$ sense if and only the map $f: Y \to X$ sending $0 \mapsto p$ and $1/n \mapsto p_n$ is continuous.

I don't have any intuition for why this result is true. Proving it doesn't seem too difficult, but I am mainly wondering why it makes sense. I know that continuity of functions in general can be thought of in terms of sequences, and it's true that a function is continuous at a point if and only if any sequence in the domain converging to that point map limits in the domain to limits in the codomain. Is this a related result?

Comment: This will be less confusing once you learn how to describe continuity in terms of topological spaces. The metric structure is not essential here. In topological terms $Y$ is the "universal convergent sequence."

Comment: The notion of continuity for a function on $Y$ is a little unintuitive, because all but one of $Y$'s points are isolated, so $Y$ is almost a [discrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) (and every function on a discrete space is continuous). The only place where continuity of $f$ at $y$ "says anything" is at $y=0$.